# Is it necessary to include plain text URLs in e-mails that have clickable links?

Tags: email, html-email

Many times I receive e-mails that have a `Confirm account` button inside them, a click-able link. At the end of the e-mail there's also a message that says:

> Trouble clicking? Copy this URL in the address bar: http://example.com/confirm-account/xyz

Why is the plain URL added at the end of the e-mail, should I include this in all my e-mails as well? Why would a `<a href="...">Confirm account</a>` not be clickable?

Answer (score 0):

It's a relic of the past =)

Now we code buttons and it works properly always. But earlier buttons were made by images. And, you guess, sometimes images doesn't appear in emails when they are in inbox (or spam folder).

So don't be worry. Coded button works OK.

Comment: Do you have a source for this answer?